# Can I replace a link on a webpage with another link depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I created a web page for a friend: [www.donjas-wellbeingforkids.co.uk](http://www.donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk)

I created a Facebook Messenger Contact Us Link straight from the contact page here: [donjaswell-beingforkids contact](http://www.donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk/contact.html)

It works great for desktop, and takes you straight to Facebook Messenger, however this does not work for mobile, as the mobile Facebook Messenger works differently, and links you to an application.

IS there any way I change the link dependent on screen size?
Below I have attached my responsive.css file and my contact.html file.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
  /*******************************************
      TWO COLUMN LAYOUT
      ********************************************/
  #primary {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  #secondary {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
  }
  /*******************************************
      COLLECTIONS
     ********************************************/
  #collections li {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 2.5%;
  }
  #collections li a p {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  #collections li a:hover p {
    font-size: 95%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  /*******************************************
      COLLECTIONS
     ********************************************/
  #collections li {
    float: left;
    width: 28.3333%;
    margin: 2.5%;
  }
  #collections li a p {
    font-size: 75%;
  }
  #collections li a:hover p {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  /*******************************************
      PAGE: ABOUT
     ********************************************/
  .profile-photo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5% 1150px 0;
  }
  #collections li a p {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  #collections li a:hover p {
    font-size: 85%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  /*******************************************
      PAGE: ABOUT
     ********************************************/
  .profile-photo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5% 800px 0;
  }
  #collections li a p {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #collections li a:hover p {
    font-size: 105%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Contact | Donja's Well-Being For Kids</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Indie+Flower|Shadows+Into+Light|Shadows+Into+Light+Two" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="favicon" type="image/png" href="img/Kids-Well-Being.png">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img id="logo" src="img/Donjas-Well-Being-For-Kids.png" alt="Donja's-Well-Being-For-Kids">
      <!--
            <h2 id="logo" class="centerText">Donja's Well-Being For Kids</h2>
            -->
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <!------------ PRODUCTS -------------------------------------
              <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
              ------------------------------------------------------------->
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section id="primary">
      <h3>General Information</h3>
      <p>For more details please contact me.</p>
      <p>I have a current DBS Certificate and also Public Liability Insurance.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="secondary">
      <h3>Contact Information</h3>
      <ul class="contact-info">
        <li class="phone"><a href="tel: 07916 337 916">Phone: 07916 337 916 </a></li>
        <li class="mail"><a href="mailto: Donja@Donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk">Email: Donja@donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk</a></li>
        <li class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1724861014479447" target="_blank">CLick to Message me on Facebook!</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--
            <h3>Hours of Operation</h3>
            <p>Monday - Friday 8:00am - 5:30pm</p>
            <h3>Address</h3>
    -->
      <p></p>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <!--        <a href="http://twitter.com/lukebennettuk"><img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>-->
      <a href="http://facebook.com/Donjaswellbeingforkids" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
      <p>&copy; 2017 Donja's Well-Being For Kids.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could have 2 links, and display the correct one using media queries... Although I think there might be a better solution... What If I'm on desktop but in a small window?

Comment: You could just have 2 link elements and toggle `display:none;` with `display:block` depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is, just use two links like so:

```
<li class="facebook desktop"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1724861014479447" target="_blank">CLick to Message me on Facebook!</a></li> 
<li class="facebook mobile"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1724861014479447" target="_blank">CLick to Message me on Facebook mobile website!</a></li>
```

And add a media query to css to hide/show the class

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I prefer adding another list item instead of hiding on anchor tags because of the extra flexibility it gives to styling the list item on the different platforms.

Comment: Yep me too! Thanks for the +!

Answer (score 1):

Here Jquery solition

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768)
{
  changeLink();
}   


function changeLink()
{
    $("a").attr("href", "Your New Link İs Here");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Include both links in your html
2. Hide the desktop link by default.
3. At the screen size you want, hide the mobile link and display the
   desktop link.

```css
.fb-desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .fb-desktop {
    display: list-item;
  }
  .fb-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="contact-info">
  <li class="phone"><a href="tel: 07916 337 916">Phone: 07916 337 916 </a></li>
  <li class="mail"><a href="mailto: Donja@Donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk">Email: Donja@donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk</a></li>
  <li class="facebook fb-desktop"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1724861014479447" target="_blank">CLick to Message me on Facebook!</a></li>
  <li class="facebook fb-mobile"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1724861014479447" target="_blank">Facebook Mobile!</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script>

    function YourFunctionName () {
        if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
            
            /
            var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("YourClassName");

            for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            anchors[i].href = "yourlink"
            
        }

          }
          else {
          }
    };

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {changelink()});

    </script>
```

Comment: Code with no explanation is a poor answer. What are you doing? Why is your answer more correct than the other 3 much older ones?

Comment: Please avoid sharing code that has syntax errors in it.